# how to get my script to display the calculation with two decimal places

Tags: javascript

I  am having a very hard time figuring out how to display my calculation to .00 decimal places. It always rounds it down/up.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    var $priceHolder = $('#creditsPrice');
    if ($priceHolder.size() === 1) {
        $('#creditsNeeded').keyup(function(e) {
            var $this = $(this),
                url = $this.attr('rel'),
                credits = parseInt($this.val(), 10);

            if (credits <= 0) {
                if ($priceHolder.is(':visible')) {
                    $priceHolder.hide();
                }
                $priceHolder.hide();
                return;
            }

            if (!$priceHolder.is(':visible')) {
                $priceHolder.show();
            }

            url += '/' + credits;

            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#js-price', $priceHolder).text(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - can you be more precise: Which variable is supposed to be rounded? Which part of your code is responsible for rounding to 2 decimals?

Comment: credits = parseInt($this.val(), 10); This is where the credits costs is devised. For whatever reason I am not able to change to a decimal. This is inherited code, but I can't find anywhere else this would be getting overridden.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the `credits` variable, it is because you are using `parseInt` which does exactly what it sounds like... parses your number into an int. Instead you can use `credits.toFixed(2)` which will return a value rounded to the closest hundredth.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish. If I replace it, I am not receiving a calculation back.

Comment: What is `$this.val()` before you call `parseInt()`? It's hard to help debug a script where we don't know the input. I might have mislead you with my original answer, as you can't just call `credits.toFixed(2)`... in this case it looks like you want `credits = parseFloat($this.val()).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: How this script works, is that it is credit amount from a form field and multiplying times a value in a db. In this case, we are attempting to multiply 5 * 5.25. No matter what I have tried, it keeps coming up as $26 not $26.25.

Comment: It looks like that calculation is happening on the server side, there could very well be some type coercion happening during the request or the handling of the request. Make sure the request is going through as you expect it to and make sure you are digesting the data correctly on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am stuck on this, because, I am not seeing anything else that would cause this. I will say it is on the CodeIgniter framework. I am still learning how all these things interact. Not sure if it is something baked in or not.